# How to do principal component regression for repeated measures?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, pca, model-selection

I have between-subject repeated measures data. I want to select the parameters for my regression model.  PCR /PCA is one option to reduce dimensionality.

How can I do this in the case of a repeated measures mixed linear model (*aka* random effect model)? As my data points are not independent, using PCR or PCA might be wrong?

Comment: AFAIK, PCA can be carried out on literally *any* matrix of numbers.  Could you explain then what you mean by "works only for IID case"?

Comment: @whuber Hi,I have between subject repeated measures data. I want to select the parameters for my regression model- PCR /PCA was one option to reduce dimensionality. But as my data points are not independent, using PCR or PCA might be wrong?